# Let $G=PH$, where $P$ is a $p$-group and $H$ is a $p’$-group, why we can consider $P=[P,H]$?

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to understand a proof in a paper named “nilpotent residual of fixed points”. The theorem in question says that: if the order of $[C_P(a), C_H(a)]$ is at most $m$ for any $ a \in A^\# $ then the order of $[P,H]$ is $(m,q)$- bounded.

Here they are considering $G=PH$, where $P$ is a normal $p$-group and $H$ is a $p’$-group and $A$ is a finite $q$- group acting on $G$ such that $P$ and $H$ are $A$ invariant.

So, my question is why can we consider that $P=[P,H]$ in the beginning of the proof?

I was thinking that in some way we can consider the quotient $G/[P,H]$ and because of it, assume that $P=[P,H]$. On the other hand, I know, by normality, that $[P,H]$ is a subgroup of $P$, but I have no idea how to prove that $P$ is contained in $[P,H]$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  What background do you have?  Please **edit the question** to provide this information.  Questions that show no independent effort to solve the problem are not well received here.

Comment: Sorry Robert, now I wrote more information and what I am thinking.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a better citation: give the author names, journal, etc. (just search for your paper on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), and then click on the speech marks `"` between the star and the "Cited by 3" of the paper you are after, and copy the format you want). Also tell us what theorem you are looking at. This information is important because it may be that you have missed a condition, or the notation is non-standard, or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H$ is a $p'$-group, we have $P = C_P(H)[P,H]$, and so $[P,H] = [[P,H],H]$. So, if $[P,H] \ne P$, then we can simply replace $P$ by $[P,H]$ and solve the problem in $[P,H]H$.

Comment: Thanks Derek, it is clear now!